# VS Code: Cmake Extension has no button on sidebar

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake

I've installed the CMake extension in VS Code. When I first worked with CMake, the installation of the extension was followed by a new button appearing on the sidebar, where I can select CMake and use the extension. Somehow, after I had to un- and reinstall VS Code, this doesn't work anymore. I can still install the CMake extension, but there is no button anywhere and I can't figure out how to access the extension. Is it possible to somehow manually add a new button on the sidebar? Or did anyone solve a similar problem?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

There are several possible reasons for your issue. Here are all I can think of right now:

1. **Make sure you've got the right extension**
   There are two popular CMake extensions:

   - One called "CMake" ([twxs.cmake](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=twxs.cmake)) which provides language support like syntax highlighting and auto completion.
   - Another one called "CMake Tools" ([ms-vscode.cmake-tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cmake-tools)) which integrates the ability to configure, build, run, debug, etc. CMake projects. This is the one that provides the sidebar for you.
2. **Make sure there is a CMakeLists.txt**
   The CMake sidebar is hidden by default and only visible if your workspace is recognized as a CMake project. This is the case if there is either a CMakeLists.txt file in the root of your workspace/opened directory or you adjust the `cmake.sourceDirectory` setting to something like `${workspaceFolder}/subdir` if your CMake project is located in a subdirectory of your workspace.
3. **Use the command palette (Crtl+Shift+P)**
   The command palette provides a lot of CMake related commands, e.g. `CMake: Configure` to configure your project. If you run this command and there is no CMakeLists.txt detected, it will ask you to "Create" or "Locate" one.
4. **Restart VS Code**
   When I created a small project to test if the extension was working on my machine, I had to restart VS Code after I manually create a CMakeLists.txt in order for the extension to detect the CMake project.
5. **Enable/Disable the CMake sidebar**
   You can right-click the sidebar (or "Activity Bar" as it is called officially) and enable/disable each available tab. Make sure the is an entry called "CMake" and that it is checked.

And since you mentioned you "can't figure out how to access the extension" ...
In general, there are a few ways to interact with the extension besides the sidebar:

- The already mentioned command palette (Ctrl+Shift+P). One of the most useful features of VS Code in my opinion.
- The status bar at the bottom lets you select the configuration (Debug/Release), the compiler kit/toolchains detected on your system as well as the default build and launch target. There are also buttons to build, run and debug your applications.
- The extension provides some shortcuts, e.g. F7 for building and Shift+F5 for debugging.

For more information please refer to the docs, [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cmake-linux) and [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/tree/develop/docs).

Comment: Obviously it was a combination of the points you mentioned. So you helped me a lot here, thanks!

Comment: Note: I was brought to this answer while searching for the extension's status bar disappearance. In case it happens to others: It may be related to the A/B experience currently conducted by the extension developers (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/issues/3202).